# Change 'Change model class name' in Django Admin || Change the 'Change' <h1>

Tags: django, django-admin

I know about:

```
class MFM(models.Model):
    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'my fancy Model'
        verbose_name_plural = 'my fancy Models'
```

but when I edit MFM in Django Admin, it says 'Change my fancy Model'. But I want it to say 'Settings on my fancy Models'.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You need to override method fo admin and you can change title according to requirement on add/change page of django admin `response.context_data['title']`

```
from .models import MFM
class MFMAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    def render_change_form(self, request, context, add=False, change=False, form_url='', obj=None):
        response = super(MFMAdmin, self).render_change_form(request, context, add, change, form_url, obj)
        response.context_data['title'] = "Settings on my fancy Models" if response.context_data['object_id'] else "Add my fancy Models"
        return response
admin.site.register(MFM, MFMAdmin)
```

Comment: Clean, but I would like a less verbose solution.