# Django Admin: How to change model name?

Tags: django, admin

I would like to change the model name displayed in admin. The idea is to be able to register filtered versions of the model to the admin view. I know that I can add filter options when viewing the model. I am not interested in doing that.

I don't think using the approach for solving admin plural naming is an option: [Django fix Admin plural](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2587707/django-fix-admin-plural). I could be wrong. If so, please tell me how this can be done.

I found this approach which seems to be the right solutions: [Change 'Change model class name' in Django Admin || Change the 'Change' <h1>](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46404568/change-change-model-class-name-in-django-admin-change-the-change-h1). However, I can't make it work. Is it just me not trying hard enough?

It is also an option to make a number of models and then register each of them. However, I will prefer to rename and register filtered versions in admin.

Any suggestions for solving this little issue?

Comment: Did you try add verbose_name to Meta class for the Model?. https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.1/ref/models/options/#verbose-name

Comment: I am not sure that you can make a list of verbose_names and then select between them. However, I could be wrong.

Comment: I am not sure, you want to have just one model with different names or better to say different aliases in Django admin panel?